# Помогите решить проблему с CSS

Tags: html, css

Эксперементирую с CSS. Обнаружил такую проблему, хотя margin равен нулю, кнопки все равно находятся на небольшом расстоянии от друг друга. Магия?

Демо: http://w-0rld.ru/news

Помогите их приклеить друг к другу.

Браузер: Chrome 44.0.2403.125 m (может проблема в нём?)

Comment: Пробелы между элементами есть?

Comment: Переносы строк? Если элементы инлайновые, то вот вам и оно.

Comment: float:left у MenuLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это проблема `display: inline-block;`

**Вариант 1:**

```
button+button {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

**Вариант 2:**

Разместить `button` без переносов.

```
... <button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button>...
```

**Вариант 3:**

```
button {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Просто и понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: Вариант 1 фиговенький

Comment: @andreymal кому что, а я им постоянно пользуюсь и еще не подводил!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="Menu">
<button class="MenuLink" id="News"><a href="/news">Новости</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button><!--
--><button class="MenuLink" id="Ticket"><a href="/ticket">Заказать</a></button>
</div>
```